# list of predef-ed params for an interface method inside the interface description

Tags: c++, com, interface, code-organization

The situation: i'm coding a COM-interface looking like

```
MIDL_INTERFACE(/*....*/)
IFace : IUnknown
{
  STDMETHOD_(void, Foo)(int param) PURE;
};
```

The interface is supposed to be used only inside my project, in few compilation units, not supposed to be placed in an idl-file. `int param` is supposed to be used in logical-`"OR"` way

```
IFace* p;
p->Foo( param1 | param2 | param3 );
```

The list of param values is statically predefined and not supposed to be modified during the program execution.

The question is: how to define the list of params? The `IFace` interface description should be placed in a file already containing many-many interfaces descriptions (hard legacy), this file is included in many places across the whole project. So, i'd like to have definition of param list inside the interface class itself.

```
IFace : IUnknown
{
  /*somehow define list of param for Foo here*/

  STDMETHOD_(void, Foo)(int param) PURE;
};
```

And use it in a way `Foo( IFace::param1 | IFace::param2 );`. I think about to make param list as `static const` variables, but i don't like the idea to place *variables* in interface-class. I can't make it with enum, because i need it with logical-OR.

Any good advices on this situation besides full reorganization of include files?

Comment: Are you sure that you can't you use enums?  The example usage you have shown is a bitwise OR, not a logical OR.  Enums will work fine in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use enums:

```
IFace : IUnknown
{
    enum { Param1 = 0x1, Param2 = 0x2, Param3 = 0x4, Param4 = 0x8 ... etc.

    STDMETHOD_(void, Foo)(int param) PURE;
};
// usage
Foo( IFace::Param1 | IFace::Param2 );
```

You can add a combination of params:

```
enum { Param1 = 0x1, Param2 = 0x2, Param1_and_2 = Param1 | Param2, ... etc.
//usage
Foo( IFace::Param1_and_2 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately the number of combinations will grow very fast with every new parameter.

Comment: Ok. Do not use combinations in enum. Or use only very frequent ones. E.g. (for open file mode) - `ReadOnly = 0x1, TextMode = 0x2. ReadOnlyText = 0x3, WriteOnly = 0x4` Do not combine `ReadOnly` and `WriteOnly`

Comment: It doesn't matter that there are a lot of combinations.  N enum values can generate 2^N combinations.